# Button is enabled with 0

Tags: java, swing, awt

So, my task is like this.
Write a program that opens a window that contains a button. The button is enabled with "0" (zero).
With every click on the button, the number in its label increments by 1.

I did the part to increment the button by 1 but I'm stuck at the part where the button should be enabled with 0. My code is like this:

```
public class Butt0n extends Frame implements ActionListener {
   private TextField text; 
   private Button button;   
   private Frame f;
   private int count = 0;    
   public Butt0n () {
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      text = new TextField(count + "", 10); // 
      text.setEditable(false);      
      add(text);                    

      button = new Button("Count");   
      add(button);                  
      button.addActionListener(this);
      setTitle("Counter");  
      setSize(300, 200);       

      setVisible(true);         

   }    


   public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Butt0n();
   }


   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      ++count; 
     text.setText(count + ""); 
   }
}
```

Any help or tips would be appretiated.

Comment: I believe you're supposed to have the `Button` contain the number, not a `TextField`. Now your button says `Count`, when it should contain (and increment) the number.

Comment: @kayaman yeah the code works but I think that it should be disabled in the beginning then enabling it by pressing 0, at least that's that what I think.

Comment: That doesn't sound very likely based on your description, and even if it were, you're still not supposed to use a `TextField`. You're supposed to use the button's label to display the number. "The number **in its label**" means the text that's written on the button, so I'm pretty sure it's your basic homework of make a `0` button that increases with each press.

Comment: You can ask your teacher for clarification. If you really need to enable the button with a keypress, you'll need a `KeyListener`.

Comment: @Kayaman Yeah you were right, I think they made a mistake translating it because it should've been **labled** and not **enabled** as they've written it. Thank you.

Comment: _"The button is enabled with "0" (zero)."_ i believe it means button is initialized with "0" : `new JButton("0")` and incremented by 1 with every click.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you should write something like:

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Butt0n extends Frame implements ActionListener {
   private Button button;
   private int count = 0;

   public Butt0n () {
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      button = new Button(count+ "");

      if(button.getLabel().equals("0")){
         button.setEnabled(true);
      }

      add(button);                  
      button.addActionListener(this);
      setTitle("Counter");  
      setSize(300, 200);       

      setVisible(true);

   }    


   public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Butt0n();
   }


   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      ++count; 
     button.setLabel(count + "");
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense either. The button will be always enabled, since it'll always be initialized with label `"0"`. It's basically a useless `if` test. Not to mention the button will be enabled by default, so you'd have to disable it, then do your useless `if` test to enable it.

Comment: I think that they test the student knowledge of awt methods, otherwise the question itself is not clear

Comment: The `if` has no effect so you can remove it. Instead of `count+ ""` you could use `String.valueOf(count)`